# Did Trump's inauguration cake copy the design of Obama's 2013 inauguration cake?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, copyright

> We have now learned that Trump continued to offer up
> Apprentice-season-four-quality optics at the “Salute to Our Troops”
> inaugural ball, where he served guests a spectacular nine-tiered cake
> made mostly of styrofoam. No one would have probably noticed if the
> design for the cake hadn’t also been ripped off without permission.
>
> Early Saturday morning, Food Network personality and baker Duff
> Goldman, who made Obama’s inaugural cake four years ago, pointed out
> on Twitter that Trump (or someone on his team) had commissioned the
> exact same cake for his own inaugural festivities, but from someone
> else.

Source: [Jezebel: Donald Trump’s Inauguration Cake Was Plagiarized, Too](http://theslot.jezebel.com/even-the-presidents-cake-is-a-lie-1791470555) (The article linked comes from a website with strong anti-Trump sentiments.)

[This tweet from from the original cake maker](https://twitter.com/Duff_Goldman/status/822675780341641216) notes the similarities:

> The cake on the left is the one I made for President Obama's inauguration 4 years ago. The one on the right is Trumps. I didn't make it.
>
> [image]

, and the tweet comes claiming to have been copied.

Was the cake at Trump's Inauguration copied from this cake artist?

Note: While the article makes reference to plagiarism, to avoid an ethical debate, this question is asking only if the cake design was *copied* from Obama's 2013 cake design.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Yes.  A [Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/food/wp/2017/01/21/trump-had-a-huge-luxurious-inauguration-cake-was-it-plagiarized/?utm_term=.bce6b171d1fa) (and interview with the Baker) includes a picture of the 2013 cake next to the 2017 cake.

The Baker of the 2013 cake [tweeted this comparison](https://twitter.com/Duff_Goldman/status/822675780341641216/photo/1).

According to the Post, Tiffany MacIsaac, owner of Washington’s Buttercream Bakeshop, which made the cake said:

> "the order came in while she was out of town and that the client had
>   brought in a photo of the cake from Obama’s inauguration, asking her
>   to re-create it."

and

> “They came to us a couple of weeks ago, which is pretty last minute,
>   and said ‘We have a photo that we would like to replicate,’ ”

According to the Posts's interview:

> MacIsaac told The Washington Post by phone. Her bakery tried to
>   encourage the client to use the photo as “inspiration,” as they do
>   with many others, she said.
>
> “They said, ‘Nope, they want this exact cake. It’s perfect.’ And we
>   said, ‘Great,’ ” MacIsaac said.

The Trump administration has not replied to requests for comment.

Comment: I hadn't seen the Washington Post article - an interview is pretty convincing evidence.

Comment: Deleted a discussion about the similarity and differences between plagiarism and copyright. Suffice to say they are very similar and very different.

Comment: if you want to link it, the "official statement" of the bakeshop that did the 2017 cake: https://www.facebook.com/ButtercreamBakeshopDC/photos/a.668484119905247.1073741832.663631600390499/1241487972604856/?type=3&theater

Comment: @BCdotWEB - I can tell you don't watch Food Network.  Most fancy party cakes are mostly styrofoam, or so it appears based on their shows about them...

Comment: @PeriataBreatta But the Obama cake wasn't: ["Obama's was made of actual cake and each tier had a different flavor cake inside"](http://www.esquire.com/news-politics/news/a52447/plagiarize-cake/).